# how to get focus to a gridview using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gridview, focus

In my web page, one button is there if I click on that button one gridview gets generated.I am using tab key to navigate through the web page...after clicking the button, the focus does not go to the gridview instead it goes to the footer elements....
Why I need Focus for gridview is to read out the content in it using nvda screen reader...
**Question**: How should I get the focus to the gridview?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What you have tried so far? And how you generating GridView? It is easy to understand when you post some of code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for it

```
$(':text').on("focus", function(){
  //here set in localStorage id of the textbox
  localStorage.setItem("focusItem", this.id);
  //console.log(localStorage.getItem("focusItem"));test the focus element id
});
```